# SQL Server: how to count rows from several databases and output in 1 table

Tags: sql-server

I have several databases and I want a list with a count of the rows of every database like this:

1. DB1 195,344
2. DB2 134,615
3. DB3 174,098

If I use the code below I get the output, although i receive the output in several individual cells. I can't copy this output. Is there a method to get the output in 1 table? I don't want to use the command UNION since i have a collation conflict between databases. Thank you!

```
select count (*) 
  FROM [2014-Apples-Part1].[dbo].[AppleData]

  select count (*) 
  FROM [2014-Apples-Part2].[dbo].[AppleData]

  select count (*) 
  FROM [2014-Apples-Part3].[dbo].[AppleData]
  etc.
```

Comment: "I can't copy this output" - yes, you can. Easier if you switch to "results to text" rather than "results to grid".

Comment: thank you. I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?];SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[AppleData]'
```

The result will appear as follows :

```
DB1    | 195344

DB2    | 134615

DB3    | 174098
```

The only pre-requisite is that `AppleData` table exists on all Databases (even system databases) or else it will generate errors.
Even with errors, the output will still come out.

You could check before doing the select if the table exists on the current database to avoid it.
Or simply filter on database IDs like on the following example :

```
sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?];if db_id()>4 SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[AppleData];'
```

You can also filter the results if you reach a certain amount of COUNT

```
sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?];
if db_id()>4
SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[AppleData]
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1000;'
```

You can also filter the results if there is no ID under a certain value

```
sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?];
if db_id()>4
SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[AppleData]
HAVING MIN(ID) >= 1000;'
```

Finally, I think the result you are expecting will be given by this request

```
sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?];
if ''?'' LIKE ''____-Apples-Part_'' 
SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[AppleData]
HAVING MIN(ID) >= 1000;'
```

Comment: This runs fine. Is there a method to exclude databases from the count?

Comment: I try to add : where ID < 1000  although i receive an error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: thanks, although i have several databases i want to exclude. Like pear1, pear2 and pear3. ID is a column i would like to ad as a where command in case records have an ID < 1000.

Comment: You mean the sum of IDs are over 1000 or at least one ID is under 1000 ?

Comment: Just one ID is under 1000

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `collate` property in the select statement.  That should take care of any inconsistencies between databases and allow for you to use `union`.

```
select 'DB1' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, count(*)
FROM [2014-Apples-Part1].[dbo].[AppleData]

union all

select 'DB2' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, count(*)
FROM [2014-Apples-Part2].[dbo].[AppleData]

union all

select 'DB3' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, count(*)
FROM [2014-Apples-Part3].[dbo].[AppleData]
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a table in one db which holds the counts,then you can use below command

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 
'USE [?];
 insert into commondb.dbo.table
 select count(*) from [dbo].[AppleData] '
```

the above command runs for each db, you can ignore system databases like below

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 
if (db_id()>4 )
begin 
 yourquery
  end
  '
```

you also can use much better versions here :

- [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)
- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/)

Comment: I have made a table Tel with table telling although when I run EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 
'USE [?];
 insert into tel.dbo.telling
 select count(*) from [dbo].[AppleData] '             I receive errors like :Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'dbo.AppleData'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'dbo.AppleData'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2

Comment: it seems ,you didnt created the table

Comment: i did, maybe because some db's dont have a table AppleData ?